# What format did old Macintoshes used?

Tags: mac, disk-format, floppy

I need what format did it used to use to revive my old Macintosh Plus. So I'm doing a research on what format did old Macintoshes used. (on hard drives or hdds). What I mean with this is what format did old macintoshes use back in the day, like a primitive version of hfs+ or something like that.

Comment: Your question, as it's currently written, is very difficult to understand.  Can you please [edit] it to add additional info and clarify the problem?  See [ask] for tips.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), so can you describe in more details which problem you are trying to solve here (and what you will do with the information you get from the answer)?

Comment: A good question for Retrocomputing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t get older than Apple File System with the first Mac.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_File_System

The Plus ships with HFS so that’s the place to start if you just need that one model.

HFS Wikipedia article as well should cover all the classic Mac OS releases. So those two likely cover all the os from System 1 to System 7 so I would focus on what system you want to run on your Mac Plus (I’d start with [System 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_6) if I were you) as opposed to what the filesystem might be. But maybe that’s all you need so start with MFS/HFS.

Comment: According to [Macintosh Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_Plus) on Wikipedia, it used the  the [Hierarchical File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_File_System) (HFS).

Comment: But MFS as well. Okay then, didn't know that my old Macintosh Plus used hfs.

Comment: Totally @user3439894 - hence the recommendation for System 6 which mandates HFS. The question is quite broad since it asks “what did old Macintoshes use” so I made it a little more general since that was doubling the possible formats.